# How to rotate single page in pdf.js

Tags: rotation, pdf.js

i downloaded pdf.js from mozilla. It works great in opening my pdf files and viewing them. The problem is when I click on the rotate page it rotates ALL the pages instead of just the selected page. I tried googled and read up the manual for pdf.js but can't find related resources on rotating SINGLE pdf page in pdf.js I don't want to rotate ALL the pdf pages. Is there any way i can get around this to just rotate ONE page? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such feature exposed via viewer. You have to implement it yourself: track individual page rotation and hook that at and/or similar to how [PDFViewer.pagesRotation setter](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/web/pdf_viewer.js#L213) is done and connected with main viewer at [PDFViewerApplication.rotatePages](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/web/viewer.js#L1216)